# What encoding to use for NSData from downloaded HTML (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Maybe my Google skills are garbage but I couldn't seem to find how to convert `NSData` of HTML to `NSString`.

I'm using `initWithData:encoding:` but if I use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` it just returns null, and if I use `NSASCIIStringEncoding` it returns my string but some elements are replaced with upside down question marks. I would just parse them out but it happens to a few different characters so I can't. Any way to change this?

EDIT: Specifically it's is an apostrophe and a dash that cause the issues.

Comment: It all depends on what encoding the actual HTML string is in to begin with. It's not ASCII, and sounds like it's not UTF8 either (although it often is with modern web servers) :) The HTTP response header may specify the encoding, or the HTML header (read as ASCII) may specify it also. Looks like you'll need to adjust dynamically.

Comment: The response headers should have a `Content-Type` value that includes the `charset` to use.

Comment: If the downloaded page contains data with mixed character sets, you probably want to do something to clean it up before running it through `initWithData:encoding:`.  A `Content-Type` header cannot entirely be trusted since any data can be returned from the server.

Comment: `Content-Type` returned `"text/html"`

Comment: @Kekoa How would you suggests going about cleaning it up?

Comment: @bipolarpants: How are you certain it's not working? What are you examining the string in? A UILabel? In the Xcode debugger?

Comment: @bipolarpants: Also, in the HTML string header, is there a tag that looks anything like this? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` This can contain the encoding as well.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, what you're getting contains non-ASCII characters, which gives you the upside down question marks.  You may be getting nil if the data cannot be encoded to UTF8 - maybe there's some control characters in your HTML?  Take a good hex dump of your data and see what you're getting.  I think you can do a

po myNSData

in the console and it will spill out your data in hex, (but clear it first) then copy and paste it into the hex field of:

[TRANSLATOR, BINARY](http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/)

to see what you're really getting.

Comment: po myNsData didn't seem to spit out any results (note, I did use my nsmutable data variable)